# how to get rid of ArrayOfString classes from jax-ws client code

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

When generating the client code from a WSDL using wsimport I am getting lot of ArrayOf*** classes.
I want to make sure that I get String[] instead of ArrayOfString.

What external customization needs to be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As of now I have done a workaround by modifying the ArrayOfXXX object in to XXX[] by using reflection in an utility method.

Comment: Have the same problem. Which also seems to be quite common. I wonder why this was not solve in WSDL2Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but if you are seeing these in your xml response, you are probably misusing the methods in the ObjectFactory class generated by JAX-WS.

For example, the two lines of code below

```
factory.createArrayOfNameListItem(factory.createArrayOfNameListItem());

factory.createMyDataItemNames(arrayOfNameListItem);
```

produce objects of the same type:

```
JAXBElement<ArrayOfNameListItem> objects
```

however

```
factory.createArrayOfNameListItem(factory.createArrayOfNameListItem());
```

serialises / renders as:

```
<ArrayOfNameListItem>
<Names>
  <NameListItem>
    <FirstName>
      Homer
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
      Simpson
    </LastName>
  </NameListItem>
</Names>
</ArrayOfNameListItem>
```

and

```
factory.createMyDataItemNames(arrayOfNameListItem);
```

serialises / renders as:

```
<Names>
  <NameListItem>
    <FirstName>
      Homer
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
      Simpson
    </LastName>
  </NameListItem>
</Names>
```

Hope this helps someone.